# Does a syntax highlighter plugin for Graql exist?

Tags: plugins, syntax, ontology, vaticle-typeql, vaticle-typedb

I cant find any **syntax highlighter plugin** for GRAKN/GRAQL language.

Does someone know where I could find them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is one for Sublime and one For VSCode. They both install from the built in installer.

Sublime:

Run the `Package Control: Install Package` command, find and install the Graql Syntax package.

VS Code:

Search for `grakn`, `graql`, or `gql`

Comment: Damnit you beat me :) just to add more. . . Link for [sublime](https://github.com/graknlabs/graql_syntax_sublime)  syntax highlighter and link for [VS code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idealley.gql) highlighter

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I was lucky ;) Drinking a coffee and my phone buzzed....

Comment: amazing, you got the answer for anything ;)

Comment: There's also a Graql syntax highlighter for IntelliJ and PyCharm!

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ, there's [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10402-graql).
Its source is on [github](https://github.com/BFergerson/JetBrains-Graql-Plugin).